# What does the "WOW64" registry-value for windows-services do?

Tags: windows-services, registry, 32bit-64bit

What does the "WOW64" value in the registry of the windows serices do, which are located in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
```

I attached an screenshot.

[image]

Here is my problem: I created a service with

```
<myserviceexe> /install
```

It looks like in the screenshot. The Serviceexecutable is compiled in 32bit and running fine.

After that i manually created a 2nd service with

```
sc create myservice binpath=C:\myservice.exe start=auto
```

The 2nd service is also compiled in 32 bit (but a completly different service than the 1st one) and running fine when created with the 2nd command. However, when creating the 2nd service, there is no WOW64 entry in the registry. If I add this entry manually (just out of curiosity for testing), the service throws an very, very, very weird error "ERROR_MORE_DATA 234: There is more data" (whatever this means) (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

Can someone explain what the WOW64 entry is doing? I find absolutly zero information online. I know what WOW64 usually means: The binary is a 32 bit binary and runs in an 32 bit environment. But what does this have to do with the services and why does my 2nd service not run when the WOW64 entry is created in the registry, although it is an 32bit binary?

Answer (score 0):

i looked what happened when starting the 2nd service with process monitor from ms-sysinternals and noticed a buffer overflow when the program loaded the WOW64 regkey, which I created manually. I then noticed i created a QWORD instead of a DWORD in the registry xD

When using an DWORD (as you should) the 2nd services also just runs fine.